# Insert picture to specific worksheet and cell with XLWINGS .pictures.add()

Tags: python, matplotlib, xlwings

I'm attempting to generate an image from a pyplot and place that image in a specific cell on a specific worksheet in Excel using xlwings. I've successfully generated the image and placed it on a worksheet, but my intent is to place multiple images in different positions on the worksheet.

Here's my code for generating the image:

```
    #Plotting the bell-shaped curve for Critical Care
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
    ccfig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    plt.plot(cc_ndist, cc_normpdf, color='black', linestyle='dashed')
    plt.scatter(cc_ndist, cc_normpdf, marker='o', s=25, color='gold')
 
    # open an existing Excel workbook with existing empty worksheet(s)
    wb = xw.Book(.....Score_2022_Q1.xlsb')
    ws1 = wb.sheets['Metrics']
    ws2 = wb.sheets['Critical Care']

    # add figures to the workbook
    ws2.pictures.add(ccfig, name='CC Plot', update=True)
```

Is there a way to either define the cell position in the .pictures.add() or in the variable of the worksheet?

Comment: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html#properties

Comment: Much appreciated, updating my post with the syntax for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
# adding left and top for the correct syntax to place the picture at cell "B2"

ws2.pictures.add(ccfig, name='CC Plot', update=True, 
                 left=ws2.range('B5').left, top=ws2.range('B5').top)
```